# How to take derivative of a scalar in gradient descent when multiplied in a matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, optimization, gradient-descent

I'm trying to use gradient descent to minimize an objective function. Part of the function is

$$F (x) = \|A - xB\|^2$$

where $A$ and $B$ are matrices, $x$ is a scalar and $\| \cdot \|$ denotes the Frobenius norm.

Using gradient descent, we have:

$$\delta F / \delta x = -2B(A-xB)$$

Then we update $x$:

$$x = x - \delta F / \delta x = x +2B(A-xB)$$

In this equation, since $A$ and $B$ are matrices, so $2B(A-xB)$ is a matrix and can't be subtracted from $x$ which is a scalar. Can someone explain to me how I can update $x$ here?

Comment: What norm are you using? This plays a big role as some are not differentiable. The Frobenius norm would probably by the most ameniable to this type of analysis

Comment: The gradient is $\frac{dF}{dx}=-2B:(A-xB)$ where the colon denotes the double-dot product, i.e. $$A:B = \sum_i\sum_j A_{ij}B_{ij}$$ As you observed, the gradient in your question is a matrix whereas the actual gradient is a scalar.

Comment: @whpowell96 It is Frobenius norm.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
F (x) &= \|A - xB\|^2_F = \sum_{i,j} (A_{ij} -x B_{ij})^2 \\
\partial_x F (x) 
&= \partial_x \sum_{i,j} (A_{ij} -x B_{ij})^2 \\
&=  \sum_{i,j} 2(A_{ij} -x B_{ij})\partial_x (A_{ij} -x B_{ij}) \\
&= -2 \sum_{i,j} (A_{ij} -x B_{ij})(- B_{ij}) \\
&= -2\left[ \sum_{i,j}A_{ij}B_{ij} - xB_{ij}^2 \right] \\
&= -2\left[ S(A\odot B) - x ||B||_F^2 \right]
\end{align}
where $\odot$ is the Hadamard product and $S(M) = \sum_{i,j} M_{i,j}$.